# Delete items from SP2013 List using excel list as filter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, delete

Is there possible a way to delete multiple items from a SharePoint 2013 list the details of which lie in an excel file.

We have an excel file of the SharePoint list data and would like to only delete those in the excel file.

How can we go about deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

Open your list as a Excel ( Ribbon option ) certin permissions will be needed use it as a Excel workbook sheet and publish your changes to SharePoint

Comment: Michal, from I see in Excel there doesnt seem to be an open from SharePoint option. I do have office 365 however we're using SharePoint On Premises

Comment: Just put your file url into File > Open. Or use the ribbon, List > Export to excel.